# Prove or disprove $\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n\right)dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n+1}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

By the given condition, the series $~~\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|~$ is convergent. Then prove or disprove:$$\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n\right)dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n+1}.$$
Now note that, since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|~$ is convergent, then we have
$$|a_n| < \frac{1}n~~\forall~~ n > N.$$
Then by Weierstrass M-test the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ is convergent. But I am not able to prove the aforesaid argument.

Comment: The series is uniformly convergent, so you can take the integral inside the sum.

Comment: Your claimed bound on $|a_n|$ is false in general. Instead, note that $$
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_n x^n } } \right| \le \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left| {a_n } \right|\left| x \right|^n }  \le \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left| {a_n } \right|}  <  + \infty 
$$ for $x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]$, i.e., the power series converges uniformly on $x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]$.

Answer (score 2):

By Hadamard's Theorem, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ converges uniformly. Then, by the integration theorem for function series you have that $\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n\right)\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\int_0^1 a_nx^n\,dx\right)$. Now, solving the integral, you get $\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n\right)\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n+1}$.

Comment: Might be worth to quote Hadamard's Theorem.

Comment: Hadamard's Theorem: The power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x-c)^n$: 1) converges absolutely $\forall x\in (c-R,c+R)$, 2) converges absolutely and uniformly $\forall x\in [c-r,c+r], r<R$, 3) doesn't converges for $x\in(-\infty,c-R)\cup (c+R,+\infty)$, 4) in $c\pm R$ we can't say anything (Abel's Theorem extends 4)), where $R=\frac{1}{\lambda}$ and $\lambda=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$.